# how to override a setter of an abstract class to make the value final

Tags: dart, inheritance, setter

Given an `abstract class` "Foo" that has a getter and setter for a "value"

```dart
abstract class Foo<T> {
  T get value;
  set value(T newValue);
}
```

I'm trying to override getter and setter to make the value final;
with the implementation below

```dart
class Bar implements Foo<String> {
  @override
  final String value;
  const Bar(this.value);
}
```

the linter complains `Missing concrete implementation of 'setter Foo.value'.`,
but if we add the implementation

```dart
class Bar implements Foo<String> {
  @override
  final String value;
  const Bar(this.value);
  @override
  set value(String newValue) => value = newValue;
}
```

when we use the setter

```dart
void main() {
  const bar = Bar('hello');
  bar.value = 'world';
  print(bar.value);
}
```

we don't receive ant warning about using the setter for a final value,
but at runtime we incur in this error

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

the problem seems to be only for the setter, therefor\

#### what is correct way to override a setter of an abstract class  to make the value final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no correct way to disable a setter in the base class because doing so is fundamentally incorrect. A derived class must be substitutable for the base class. If the derived class did not provide a setter, then it would no longer be providing the base class's interface and would violate [the substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Consider:

```dart
void updateFoo<T>(Foo<T> foo, T newValue) => foo.value = newValue;

void main() {
  var bar = Bar('hello');
  updateFoo(bar, 'world');
}
```

It is not possible to issue any compile-time warnings or errors; the implementation and call of `updateFoo` are both legal from static analysis.

Instead consider:

- Inverting the class hierarchy if possible: make read-only classes the base classes and provide setters or mutators in the derived classes.
- Accept a setter that either does nothing (although callers likely would not expect that) or that throws an exception at runtime (this is what things such as [`UnmodifiableListView`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/UnmodifiableListView-class.html) do).

Also, your specific exception occurs because of a different mistake in your implementation.  When you do:

```dart
  @override
  set value(String newValue) => value = newValue;
```

then the `value = newValue;` statement will trigger the `value` setter *again*, resulting in infinite recursion as hinted at by the error message.  If you instead tried to do:

```dart
  final String _value;

  @override
  String get value => _value;

  @override
  set value(String newValue) => _value = newValue;
```

then your `Bar` implementation would have generated a compile-time error for trying to reassign `_value`, which is `final`.  And if you made `_value` non-`final`, then the compiler would have generated a compile-time error telling you that `Bar` then could not have a `const` constructor.